# Counting unique elements in a list

Tags: list, haskell, unique

Is there a straight-forward combination of standard higher-order functions to count the unique elements in a list?

For example the result for

```
[1, 1, 4, 0, 4, 4]
```

would be something like

```
[(1,2), (4,3), (0,1)]
```

Comment: Is order important? If so what is the order? Order of first occurrence?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If order is not important this works:

```
map (\xs@(x:_) -> (x, length xs)) . group . sort
```

`group . sort` will give you a list of lists where all elements that are equal to each other are grouped into the same sublist (without sort, only consecutive equal elements would be grouped together). The `map` then turns each sublist into a `(element, lengthOfSublist)`-tuple.

If you want to order the result by first occurrence, you can use `zip` before the sort to add an index to each element, then, after grouping, sort again by that index and then remove the index.

Comment: The sort could be very expensive on large lists. It might be better to use KennyTM's or sdcwc's solutions for faster performance.

Comment: @GeneralBecos Why would sorting be slower than creating a map? Both are `O(n log n)`.

Comment: Because assuming you are doing a frequency distribution, the number of elements in only the worst case will be the same as the number of elements in the list. In the more common scenario, the number of elements in the distribution will be far smaller. Therefor on average, the map will outperform the sort.

Comment: @GeneralBecos Yes, the number of elements in the map will be smaller, but I don't see how that makes the creation of the map cheaper. You're still calling `insert` once for every element in the list and each call to `insert` takes `O(log n)` time - whether the element is already in the map or not.

Comment: It will take `O(log n)` in the worst case. On average it will take `O(log m)` where `m << n`

Comment: @GeneralBecos Ah, I see now. Yes, that's true.

Comment: Do I still deserve that negative rep? :-(

Comment: @GeneralBecos What negative rep?

Comment: I think I got flagged for the comment as unconstructive, offensive or spam.

Answer (score 14):

Using Data.Map and tuple sections:

```
 count = Map.fromListWith (+) . map (, 1)
```

(Add `Map.toList` if you need a list.)

Answer (score 7):

The simplest thing would be to sort the items into order, use "group" to put them into sub-lists of equal elements, and then count the items in each sub-list.

```
map (\xs -> (head xs, length xs)) . group . sort
```

Comment: By the way you can write `\xs -> (head xs, length xs)` as `head &&& length`, using Control.Arrow module.

Answer (score 6):

If the list contains only integers, you could also use

```
 import qualified Data.IntMap as I

 countElems1 :: [Int] -> [(Int, Int)]
 countElems1 = I.toList . foldr (\k -> I.insertWith (+) k 1) I.empty
```

(Remember to compile with optimization though, otherwise this will be 2x slower than the `group . sort` method. With `-O2` it is slightly faster by 14%.)

You could also use one of the [multiset](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/multiset) [packages](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/multiset-comb/0.2.1/doc/html/Math-Combinatorics-Multiset.html) which makes the function as simple as

```
 import qualified Math.Combinatorics.Multiset as S
 countElems4 = S.toCounts . S.fromList
```

but being less efficient.

All of the above solutions ignore the original order.

Comment: And that's without the recent speed improvements to the containers library, I'll bet.

Answer (score 1):

What your talking about is just [run length encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) on sorted data: the free online book Real World Haskell has a [great example of this](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/barcode-recognition.html#Barcode.hs:runLength). You will want to sort the list before you put it through the runLengthEncoder.

Comment: It is *not* RLE. RLE will give `[(1,2),(4,1),(0,1),(4,2)]`.

Comment: @KennyTM Please note that I said 'on sorted data'. So not quite RLE but almost with sorted input I think it is; isn't it?