# Haskell - get items that occur only once

Tags: haskell, duplicates

Im trying to figure out how to create a new list that has only the elements that occur only once. I can't use recursion either.

This is a small part of a bigger function. Im trying to write a function to get the Intersect of two sets. Basically i combined the sets. Then sorted. Then i want to combine that with set B and get rid of all the duplicates in that set. Unless someone else knows an easier way.

I can use high order functions, but i can't use recursion.

Thanks

Edit:
Example:

[1,2,3,3,4,4,5,5] Should come out as [1,2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question was already asked before and essentially you just want to group them together by counting the number of elements and then only extracting those with a count of one. (probably using ['filter'](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.0/Prelude.html#v:filter))

Please see [Counting unique elements in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710976/counting-unique-elements-in-a-list/3713886#3713886)

Comment: The question is tagged as homework, so he probably wants hints more than someone to solve it for him

Comment: you're a genius if i can use group.

Comment: @Daenyth yeah but the first part of doing homework is doing your research. I wanted to show that perhaps a little more time searching would have led to the answer, maybe.

Comment: @Matt hopefully you can and then hopefully it helps; better yet if you understand why it works then that is good enough for me.

Comment: I had searched on here, but couldnt find anything as i didn't want to count unique elements, but just gather the ones that had no duplicates. But i didn't even know about the "group" function. I did come up with a way to do what i need to do with group, just need to see if i can use it now.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this hint is sufficiently vague. :)

Think about grouping duplicate elements together.

Comment: I know how to zip and then get rid of the duplicates. But i only want the elements that occur only once. Edited my question with an example.

Comment: Do you think it would help if the, now adjacent, elements were themselves in smaller, internal lists?

Comment: Oh I see, I get no love for trying to help the OP to come up with the answer on his own. bah

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but i would have still sat there scratching my head. I didn't know about the group function in haskell.

Answer (score 1):

Think about what data structure you'd use to keep track of how many times each thing shows up.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
concat $ filter (null . tail) $ group [1,2,3,3,4,4,5,5]
```