# dictionary in python 2.7

Tags: python, optimization, dictionary

I am new to python and I have a question.
In this script I rename the elements of a string.
For a small input z < 1mb text file time is small. If I try input more than 2Mb it takes over 1 hour.

Is the time problem caused by the dictionary?
Should I try to approach it via list or set?
I have seen this article [Python: List vs Dict for look up table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513882/python-list-vs-dict-for-look-up-table) about dicts being better than lists. I am a bit confused.

Comment: What the heck are you trying to do? I understand what the code does, but I'm curious as to its application. Why are you doing this?

Comment: Be more explicit, particularly what are `z` and `d`? Also there's a useful module called `timeit` that does the thing you're doing here manually (timing code execution).

Comment: Input is an Inverted File, so I try to rename all the records to decrease the DGaps

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all `if word in d.keys()` is **very slow** as it builds the list consisting of all `d` keys each time. you should use `if word in d` instead (it is **much** faster as it does not create new obkects)

Comment: Also, `if word in d.keys()` does a *list* search (linear time); `if word in d` does a *dictionary* search (constant time).

Comment: @nneonneo well... not really constant: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: @Dunno: Amortized/expected constant-time. (I was going to gloss over the "amortized" bit because it's not relevant to the comparison)

Answer (score 1):

You should try

```
result = [(item, count(item)) for item in set(the_list)]
```

as your code is basically counting the number of apparition of one word in your list.

See this SO question --> [how to optimally count elements in a python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456700/how-to-optimally-count-elements-in-a-python-list)